EXCEL Split an integer number into several integer numbers
I've got an integer number that I want to split into six different integers so that their proportions match given weights as closely as possible. Example below:

What's the cleanest way to do it? I've done it using a complicated combination of ROUNDDOWN and RANK, but it's not 100% fool-proof.

With the data laid out as in the answer posted, you could use =IF(ROW()-1<COUNT($B$2:$B$7),ROUND($A$2*B2/SUM($B$2:$B$7),0),A$2-SUM(C$1:C1)) in C2 and copy down - this effectively rounds all the weights bar the last, to which is allocated the impact of any roundings.

Okay, this may be slightly overcomplicated, but:
=LET(total,$A$2,weights,$B$2:$B$7,valTbl,MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(weights),2,LAMBDA(y,x,IF(x=1,y,total*INDEX(weights,y)/SUM(weights)))),sortTbl,SORTBY(valTbl,MOD(INDEX(valTbl,,2),1),-1),lowtotal,SUM(ROUNDDOWN(INDEX(valTbl,,2),0)),outTbl,MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(weights),2,LAMBDA(y,x,ROUNDDOWN(INDEX(sortTbl,y,x),0)+IF(AND(x=2,y<=(total-lowtotal)),1,0))),INDEX(SORT(outTbl,1,1),,2))

(Due to using the LAMBDA and MAKEARRAY functions, this will not work in older version of Excel)
How it works:
First, it creates the valTbl array, which contains the Row Number and the exact proportional value (including decimals)



Row
Value




1
134.359


2
87.33333


3
80.61538


4
53.74359


5
26.87179


6
403.0769



Then it sorts this, Descending, by the decimal portion of the value into sortTbl:



Row
Value




5
26.87179


4
53.74359


3
80.61538


1
134.359


2
87.33333


6
403.0769



It sums up the Integer portions of the values (783), subtracts that from the total (786-783 = 3) which we will temporarily refer to as , then creates the new outTbl by taking the Integer portions of the values, and adding 1 to the first  entries:



Row
Value




5
27 (+1)


4
54 (+1)


3
81 (+1)


1
134 (+0)


2
87 (+0)


6
403 (+0)



Finally, we sort this, Ascending, by the Row, (which puts it back into the original order) and output only the Value column:



Result




134


87


81


54


27


403




Due to the way this works, this even functions for cases such as when our Weights result in matching Decimal Portions: (This prioritises earlier rows, but you could extend the SortBy to change that if you wanted to prioritise larger or smaller Integer values or something)



Number
Weight
→
Row¹
Value¹
→
Row²
Value²
→
Row³
Value³
→
Result




100
3
→
1
33.3333
→
1
33.3333
→
1
34 (+1)
→
34



3
→
2
33.3333
→
2
33.3333
→
2
33 (+0)
→
33



3
→
3
33.3333
→
3
33.3333
→
3
33 (+0)
→
33



or even



Number
Weight
→
Row¹
Value¹
→
Row²
Value²
→
Row³
Value³
→
Result




100
1
→
1
8.3333
→
1
8.3333
→
1
9 (+1)
→
9



4
→
2
33.3333
→
2
33.3333
→
2
33 (+0)
→
33



7
→
3
58.3333
→
3
58.3333
→
3
58 (+0)
→
58




Excellent answer. I likely won't work with the older Excel I've got at home, but it contains the answer in a single formula. (I've used the same methodology, but had to store intermediate results in cells rather than arrays.)

Try the following:


=ROUND($A$2*(B2/SUM(B$2:B$7)),0)


Or, Can spill it:
=LET(α,B2:B7,ROUND(A2*α/SUM(α),0))



That won't work. In the example above, consider what happens if you change the last weight from 60 to 12, the results will add up to 787 and not 786.

@JakubSzyguła ah yes i will update

To use the most straightforward example of how I expect problematic roundings to be handled. Splitting 7 into 6 parts with equal weights should give 2 1 1 1 1 1 .

@JakubSzyguła the reverse is not working because of floating issues.

I would just sort the weights from largest to smallest first.
For the first five, use =ROUND($A$2*D2/SUM($D$2#),0) to round to the nearest integer.
Then for the last weight just use =A2-SUM(E2:E6) to ensure sum is always 786.
Not mathematically rigorous but I think it should work most of the time.


Consider the weighting "10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 4".  The first 5 entries are (without rounding) 145.5556, which you round to 146 — but the 6th entry is (without rounding) 58.222, yet you output 56…

@Chronocidal  Yes, your version is much better.

If you have MS365 then this LAMBDA formula would yield the desired results

=LET(tgt,F2,weights,G2:G7,fx,tgt/SUM(weights),sub,REDUCE(0,DROP(weights,1),LAMBDA(a,c,a+ROUND(fx*c,0))),BYROW(weights,LAMBDA(r,IF(ROW(r)=ROW(tgt),tgt-sub,ROUND(fx*r,0)))))

If both of the following conditions are satisfied:

the number is less than the sum of the weights
there are weights of negligible value

then the function may yield zero or negative-value allocations (although these would, technically, still be integer numbers).
(if, as I suspect, this is some sort of financial-allocation exercise, both will never be true)
